# Selenium 2 & keypress

Tags: keypress, selenium-webdriver

I just upgraded to Selenium 2 and having trouble simulating a keypress in firefox (maybe other browsers?). First of all, the new API, using IWebDrivers, does not provide a keypress funktion. I can acquire a ISelenium instance with the 1.0 API (WebDriverBackedSelenium) functions, however I receive an error when using this. E.g.

```
new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, TestServerUrl).KeyDownNative("27");
```

yields

> System.NotSupportedException : keyDownNative

The same is the case for KeyDown, KeyPress etc. Is this not supported in Selenium v2?

Thanks in advance!

/Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so to future reader - I read some of ThoughtWorks documentation and the Selenium v2 API is not quite implemented yet.

So note to self - Big difference between v1 and v2 and v2 API not fully implemented.

Comment: New discovery - e.g. use .SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown)

Answer (score 0):

To send key presses to an *WebElement* using Selenium 2 (i.e. to an input field) you can do the following:

```
// Retrieve the required WebElement object of interest //
WebElement myElement = getWebelement();

// send some chars
myElement.sendKeys("Some Test Text");
```

Also, to delete text from a WebElement (i.e. an input box) you could do the following:

```
String BACK_SPACE_UNICODE_CODE = "\u0008";

WebElement inputElement = getWebelement();
String currentValue = inputElement.getAttribute("value");

if (!"".equals(currentValue))
{
    for (int count=0;count< currentValue.length();count++)
    {
        inputElement.sendKeys(BACK_SPACE_UNICODE_CODE);
    }            
}
```

Probably best to put this code within a function so it can be used throughout your tests.